# Visual C++ Как получить вывод в консоль только от моего приложения?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, консоль

Пишу консольное приложение. В консоль выводится информация о текущих выполняемых задачах. В процессе работы, для выполнения некоторых задач, запускаются сторонние консольные утилиты, через CreateProcess. И их вывод естествено смешивается с выводом моего приложения. Как организовать вывод только от моего приложения, чтобы от вывод запускаемыхприложений не смешивался с моим?

Answer (score 1):

Можно запускать сторонние консольные утилиты с параметром, перенаправляющим вывод в файл или на нулевой устройство. Что-то вроде:

```
utils.exe > file.txt
```

или

```
utils.exe > null
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть много способов сделать это:

*Первый:* перенаправить ввод/вывод приложения в файл;

*Второй:* запретить наследие дескрипторов и открывать приложения скрытыми;

*Третий:* если вы хотите сохранить вывод, но не отображать его, то просто создайте `pipe` на каждый дескриптор (`stdout`, `stdin` и `stderr`), провести некоторые манипуляции с дублирование и запретом наследование некоторых дескрипторов (Например: для `stdin` дочернего процесса следует следует дублировать входодной дескриптор и запретить его наследие, дабы не случился казус с вводом).

И это ещё не все возможные способы.